# Is Lambda Lifting necessary?

Tags: haskell, compiler-optimization

Many functional programming language's compiler has a Lambda Lifting pass, and I'm wondering, is this the best way to implement a functional programming language?

Let's consider the following example:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo = \x -> \y -> x * x * x + y

main = print $ sum (map (foo 5) [0..100])
```

if without lambda lifting, we need to calc `x * x * x` only 1 time, but if with lambda lifting, we will need to calc `x * x * x` 100 times.

So I'm wondering, did GHC always do lambda lifting even in the above case? is it necessary? Or is there any alternative FP lang compiling technology which can handle the above case better?

Comment: Look at the "full laziness" transformation

Comment: As I understand it the Haskell compiler is implemented using graph reduction; shouldn't this take care of that problem at compile time? (just a thought...)

Comment: The GHC Core output for this program evaluates `x * x * x` exactly once. We need to consider much more than lambda lifting to reason about program performance. Also, GHC does closure conversion instead of lambda lifting AFAIK, strictly speaking.